# Struts2 pre-test ServletContext

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have two Struts2 Action classes - 'SetupAction' and 'MainAction'. 'SetupAction' sets up some file locations to read files. It implements the ServletContextListener:

```
@WebListener
public class SetupAction implements ServletContextListener {....}
```

I want to test methods in my 'MainAction' using JUnit4, in addition to using Cargo and Failsafe plugins to start a Tomcat7 instance before running tests and tearing it down afterwards.

The problem is I need 'SetupAction' to complete setup before running the tests. I want to run this as if it's on a real server which is why I'm avoiding mocks.

proxy.getAction() in 'MainAction' will return 'SetupAction' if I send a HTTP GET request to the server at the start of the test.

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that's what's happening. Have you actually verified things aren't working?

Comment: @DaveNewton Good point, assumption on my part which I'll edit out. I'm not sure what you mean but I have verified things ARE working as they should in a normal run through. The issue is only in testing.

Comment: I'm also concerned about using a Struts action to initialize anything; is it really a Struts action? Why?

Comment: It extends ActionSupport but only has the contextInitialized and contextDestroyed functions. It's based on what I have to do at work so I'm not sure why.